# react-query custom hook how to use useMutation and useQuery conditionaly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

i create custom hook for use useQuery() :

```
export const useRequest = (
  {
    path = "",
    params = {},
    body = {},
    key = "",
    options= {},
    method = "get"
  }
) => {

  // async function for get API:
  const callApi = async () => {
    const { data: { response } } = await axios[method](baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }

  const query = useQuery(key, callApi, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    ...options
  });

  return { ...query, isLoading: query.isLoading && query.fetchStatus !== "idle" }
}
```

To use the useMutation hook without using the separate function, I changed my useRequest() as follows:

```
export const useRequest = (
  {
    path = "",
    params = {},
    body = {},
    key = "",
    options= {},
    method = "get",
    mutation = false
  }
) => {

  // async function for get API:
  const callApi = async () => {
    const { data: { response } } = await axios[method](baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }
  
  if (mutation) {
    const callMutationApi = async (data) => {
      const {params, body} = data;
      const { data: { response } } = await axios.post(baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
        {
          params,
          ...body
        });

      return response;
    }

    return useMutation(callMutationApi, options);
  }

  const query = useQuery(key, callApi, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    ...options
  });

  return { ...query, isLoading: query.isLoading && query.fetchStatus !== "idle" }
}
```

But I get the following error:
React Hook "useMutation" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

What changes should I make in the useRequest() function? Thank you for your guidance.

***///// UPDATE /////***

According to the answer of dear @kapobajza...

I changed the code as follows and it worked:

```
export const useRequest = (
  {
    path = "",
    params = {},
    body = {},
    key = "",
    options= {},
    method = "get",
    mutation = false
  }
) => {

  // async function for get API:
  const callApi = async () => {
    const { data: { response } } = await axios[method](baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }


  const callMutationApi = async (data) => {
    const {params, body} = data;
    const { data: { response } } = await axios.post(baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }

  // Instead of returning here, just save the result in a variable
  const useMutationResult = useMutation(callMutationApi, options);

  const query = useQuery(key, callApi, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: (!mutation && options?.enabled),
    ...options
  });
  
  // If mutation is defined, return that result
  if (mutation) {
    return useMutationResult;
  }

  return { ...query, isLoading: query.isLoading && query.fetchStatus !== "idle" }
}
```

I added the option part of the following code to useQuery().. This will prevent useQuery() from running:

```
{
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: (!mutation && options?.enabled),
    ...options
}
```

Please tell me if this solution is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot call React hooks conditionally.

> One thing you'll find out early adopting react is that you cannot have conditional hooks. This is because every hook is initially added into a list that is reviewed on every render cycle, so if the hooks don't add up, there is something amiss and any linter set up correctly will warn you.

[Taken from this article](https://dev.to/lexlohr/conditional-hooks-1fpj#:%7E:text=One%20thing%20you%27ll%20find,up%20correctly%20will%20warn%20you.)

But the thing you could do is to return the result of the `useMutation` hook if `mutation` is defined:

```
export const useRequest = (
  {
    path = "",
    params = {},
    body = {},
    key = "",
    options= {},
    method = "get",
    mutation = false
  }
) => {

  // async function for get API:
  const callApi = async () => {
    const { data: { response } } = await axios[method](baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }


  const callMutationApi = async (data) => {
    const {params, body} = data;
    const { data: { response } } = await axios.post(baseUrl._serviceUrl + path,
      {
        params,
        ...body
      });

    return response;
  }

  // Instead of returning here, just save the result in a variable
  const useMutationResult = useMutation(callMutationApi, options);

  const query = useQuery(key, callApi, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    ...options
  });
  
  // If mutation is defined, return that result
  if (mutation) {
    return useMutationResult;
  }

  return { ...query, isLoading: query.isLoading && query.fetchStatus !== "idle" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But there is a problem, the automatic useMutation() function is called without calling the mutate() function!

Comment: @MasoudTesna and what is the purpose of `mutate` being automatically called?  As far as I can see in the docs, there is no option to call `mutate` automatically when `useMutation` is being called.

Comment: Please see the answer I sent

Comment: dear @kapobajza I found a solution.

The problem was from useQuery() that was running! There is an option called Enabled, which I changed as follows:
`enabled: (!mutation && options?.enabled),`
Do you think it's right?